# How to Scan the BLE device in background service without library?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-service

I am trying to connect BLE device with android application. I am getting the device name,Mac Address and rssi value in foreground. I dont know how to scan the device in background and get the details of that particular device like MAC address,rssi value.

Comment: What do you mean you are getting the device name,Mac Address and rssi value in foreground? If you do a time-consuming operation such as bluetooth scanning in UI thread,this will block the UI thread.And most of the time the scan method will do it in the worker thread inside.Can you post some code?

Answer (score 5):

You have to do all in the background for that start sticky service and in onStartCommand of that services start scanning.

```
package com.myapp.services;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.R;

/**Both RX and RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication) are indications of the power level being received 
 * by an antenna
 * The difference between RX and RSSI is that RX is measured in milliWatts (mW) or decibel-milliwatts (dBm) 
 * whereas RSSI is a signal strength percentage—the higher the RSSI number, the stronger the signal
 *
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class BeaconService extends Service implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback{
    private static final String TAG = BeaconService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothGatt btGatt;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        writeLine("Automate service created...");
        getBTService();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        writeLine("Automate service start...");
        if (!isBluetoothSupported()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopSelf();
        }else{
            if(mBluetoothAdapter!=null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                startBLEscan();                     
            }else{
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        writeLine("Automate service destroyed...");
        stopBLEscan();
        super.onDestroy();

        if(btGatt!=null){
            btGatt.disconnect();
            btGatt.close();
            btGatt = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        writeLine("Automate service stop...");
        stopSelf();
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    public BluetoothAdapter getBTService(){
        BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = (BluetoothAdapter) btManager.getAdapter();
        return mBluetoothAdapter;
    }

    public boolean isBluetoothSupported() {
        return this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
    }

    public void startBLEscan(){
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
    }

    public void stopBLEscan(){
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param enable
     */
    public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            startBLEscan();
        } else {
            stopBLEscan();
        }
    }

    public static void enableDisableBluetooth(boolean enable){
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if(enable) {
                bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            }else{
                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        if(device!=null && device.getName()!=null){
            //Log.d(TAG + " onLeScan: ", "Name: "+device.getName() + "Address: "+device.getAddress()+ "RSSI: "+rssi);
            if(rssi > -90 && rssi <-1){
                writeLine("Automate service BLE device in range: "+ device.getName()+ " "+rssi);
                if (device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("NCS_Beacon") || device.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("estimote")) {
                    //This Main looper thread is main for connect gatt, don't remove it
                    // Although you need to pass an appropriate context getApplicationContext(),
                    //Here if you use Looper.getMainLooper() it will stop getting callback and give internal exception fail to register //callback
                    new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, bleGattCallback);
                            Log.e(TAG, "onLeScan btGatt value returning from connectGatt "+btGatt);
                        }
                    });
                }
                stopBLEscan();  
            }else{
                //Log.v("Device Scan Activity", device.getAddress()+" "+"BT device is still too far - not connecting");
            }
        }
    }

    BluetoothGattCallback bleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            writeLine("Automate service connection state: "+ newState);
            if (newState == android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
                writeLine("Automate service connection state: STATE_CONNECTED");
                Log.v("BLEService", "BLE Connected now discover services");
                Log.v("BLEService", "BLE Connected");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        writeLine("Automate service go for discover services");
                        gatt.discoverServices();
                    }
                }).start();
            }else if (newState == android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                writeLine("Automate service connection state: STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                Log.v("BLEService", "BLE Disconnected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                writeLine("Automate service discover service: GATT_SUCCESS");
                Log.v("BLEService", "BLE Services onServicesDiscovered");
                //Get service
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                writeLine("Automate service discover service imei: " +imei);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,  int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        }
    };

    private void writeLine(final String message) {
        Handler h = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

In manifest.xml

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Permission for bluetooth -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

 <service
            android:name="com.myapp.services.BeaconService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: you're the best.

Comment: This is not working. Can you please help??. I have a client app and a server app that has its background service code written by you. But the client is unable to scan the server device app.

Comment: @priyankasinghal, are you sure that your service gets started properly. What is your target SDK version in build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Use service to scan and connect ble devices when application is in background in android.

```
package com.example.tracker.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.example.tracker.R;
import com.example.tracker.utils.SampleGattAttributes;
import com.example.tracker.utils.SharedPreferencesUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import static com.example.tracker.constant.SharedFreferencesConstant.KEY_SP_MOBILE_NUMBER;

/**
 * Created by Jprashant on 12/9/17.
 */

public class BackgroundService extends Service{

    private int scanPeriod;

    Context context;
    String TAG="BackgroundService";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;
    public String[] advDataTypes = new String[256];

    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDeviceArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo=new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;


    /*Connect Ble Device*/



    String deviceId;
    public static String arrayDidOpnSec2;

    BluetoothGattService gattService4;
    public static ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> lastCharacteristic;


    //    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
    private float avgRssi = 0.0f;
    // private Dialog dialog;
    private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
    private boolean mConnected = false;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList();

    //service and char uuid
    private static final int TRACKER_ON_OFF = 2;
    private static final UUID TRACER_TRIPPLE_PRESS_SERVICE=UUID.fromString("edfec62e-9910-0bac-5241-d8bda6932a2f");
    private static final UUID TRACKER_TRIPPLE_PRESS_CHAR=UUID.fromString("772ae377-b3d2-4f8e-4042-5481d1e0098c");
    private static final UUID IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    private static final UUID ALERT_LEVEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private Button btnSMS;
    public static String mDeviceName,mDeviceAddress,connectionStatus;

    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PreferencesFile";

    public int deviceCount = 0;

    public String[] mData = new String[400];
    private Handler mHandler1;

    private ListView listItems;


    /*--------for > 21--------------*/
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;




    public BackgroundService() {

    }

    public BackgroundService(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

//        getting systems default ringtone

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CALL YOUR METHOD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mHandler = new Handler();

                // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
                // selectively disable BLE-related features.
                if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
                // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
                final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

                // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
                    advDataTypes[i] = "Unknown Data Type";
                }
                advDataTypes[REQUEST_ENABLE_BT] = "Flags";
                advDataTypes[2] = "Incomplete List of 16-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[3] = "Complete List of 16-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[4] = "Incomplete List of 32-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[5] = "Complete List of 32-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[6] = "Incomplete List of 128-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[7] = "Complete List of 128-bit Service Class UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[8] = "Shortened Local Name";
                advDataTypes[9] = "Complete Local Name";
                advDataTypes[10] = "Tx Power Level";
                advDataTypes[13] = "Class of LocalDevice";
                advDataTypes[14] = "Simple Pairing Hash";
                advDataTypes[15] = "Simple Pairing Randomizer R";
                advDataTypes[16] = "LocalDevice ID";
                advDataTypes[17] = "Security Manager Out of Band Flags";
                advDataTypes[18] = "Slave Connection Interval Range";
                advDataTypes[20] = "List of 16-bit Solicitaion UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[21] = "List of 128-bit Solicitaion UUIDs";
                advDataTypes[22] = "Service Data";
                advDataTypes[23] = "Public Target Address";
                advDataTypes[24] = "Random Target Address";
                advDataTypes[25] = "Appearance";
                advDataTypes[26] = "Advertising Interval";
                advDataTypes[61] = "3D Information Data";
                advDataTypes[255] = "Manufacturer Specific Data";
                scanPeriod = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).getInt("scan_interval", 6000);
                scanTrackerDevices();
            }
        }, 10000);




        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void scanTrackerDevices(){
        Log.e(TAG,"scanTrackerDevices");

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            }
        }
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }


    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        bluetoothDeviceArrayList.clear();
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    int arraySize=bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo.size();
                    Log.e(TAG,"bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo Size in scan :"+arraySize);

                     for (int i=0;i<bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo.size();i++){
                        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice=bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo.get(i);
                        Log.e(TAG,"Device Name in scan :"+bluetoothDevice.getName());
                        Log.e(TAG,"Device Address in scan :"+bluetoothDevice.getAddress());

                         if (i==0){
                             mBluetoothLeService.connect(bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                         }
                        }
                }
            }, scanPeriod);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }




    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

                    String d = "";
                    String rd = "";
                    String h = "0123456789ABCDEF";
                    int ln = 0;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < scanRecord.length) {
                        int x = scanRecord[i] & 255;
                        rd = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(rd)).append(h.substring(x / 16, (x / 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(h.substring(x % 16, (x % 16) +REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).toString();
                        if (i == ln) {
                            ln = (i + x) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT;
                            if (x == 0) {
                                break;
                            }
                            d = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(d)).append("\r\n     Length: ").append(h.substring(x / 16, (x / 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(h.substring(x % 16, (x % 16) +REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).toString();
                            i += REQUEST_ENABLE_BT;
                            x = scanRecord[i] & 255;
                            d = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(d)).append(",   Type :").append(h.substring(x / 16, (x / 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(h.substring(x % 16, (x % 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(" = ").append(advDataTypes[x]).append(",   Value: ").toString();
                            rd = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(rd)).append(h.substring(x / 16, (x / 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(h.substring(x % 16, (x % 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).toString();

                        } else {
                            d = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(d)).append(" ").append(h.substring(x / 16, (x / 16) + REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).append(h.substring(x % 16, (x % 16) +REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)).toString();
                        }
                        i += REQUEST_ENABLE_BT;
                    }


                    Log.e(TAG,"UUID : "+device.getUuids());
                    String[] arrayDeviceName=String.valueOf(device.getName()).split(" ");
                    String deviceName0=arrayDeviceName[0];
                        bluetoothDeviceArrayListTwo.add(device);


        }
    };



    /*-------------------Connect BLE---------------------------------------------*/

        private Handler mHandler2;


        public final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();


            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action))
            {
                numberOfRssi = 0;
                avgRssi = 0.0f;
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                mHandler2.postDelayed(startRssi, 300);
                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED");

            }


            else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED");


            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                displayGattServicesForDimmer(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());// For dimmer

                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED");


            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE");
                String unknownServiceString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
                displayDimmerData("<<" + SampleGattAttributes.lookup(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.CHARACTERISTIC_UUID), unknownServiceString) + ">> Value: " + intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA) + "]");
                displayDimmer2(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));


            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_RSSI_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
                updateRssi(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA, -400));

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_WRITE_FAILED.equals(action)) {
                Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_GATT_WRITE_FAILED");

            }

        }
    };







    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
//    -------------------Connect Ble--------------------------------------

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_RSSI_UPDATE);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_WRITE_FAILED);

        Log.e(TAG,"OnResume()");

        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BluetoothLeService.class), mServiceConnection, 1);

        mHandler2=new Handler();
    }





    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");

            }
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };
    private boolean notificationActive = true;
    private int numberOfRssi = 0;


    private Runnable startRssi = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mConnected) {
                mBluetoothLeService.readRemoteRssi();
                mHandler2.postDelayed(startRssi, 200);
            }
        }
    };



    public BluetoothGatt getmGatt() {
        return mGatt;
    }

    //code from DeviceControlActivity
    private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
        connectionStatus= String.valueOf(resourceId);
        Log.e(TAG,"Resource ID"+resourceId);

    }

    private void displayDimmerData(String data){
        Log.e(TAG,"Display Data :"+data);


    }

    private void displayDimmer2(String data){
        Log.e(TAG,"display Dimmer2"+data);


        String sosString = data.substring(0, Math.min(data.length(), 3));
        Log.e(TAG,"SOS String :"+sosString);
        if (sosString.equals("SOS")){
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ SharedPreferencesUtils.getStringFromSharedPreferences(KEY_SP_MOBILE_NUMBER,getApplicationContext())));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    }

    private void updateRssi(int data) {
        if (data > -400) {
            if (this.numberOfRssi > 10) {
                this.avgRssi = ((9.0f * this.avgRssi) + ((float) data)) / 10.0f;
            } else {
                this.avgRssi = (this.avgRssi + ((float) data)) / 2.0f;
                this.numberOfRssi++;
            }
            connectionStatus="Connected, RSSI:" + data + ",  Avg:" + Math.round(this.avgRssi);

        }
    }

    /*-------------------------disaplay gatt service for dimmer----------------------*/
    private void displayGattServicesForDimmer(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {

        if (gattServices != null) {

            String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
            String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData = new ArrayList();
            this.mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList();


            for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap();
                String uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
                currentServiceData.put("NAME", SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
                currentServiceData.put("UUID", uuid);
                gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData = new ArrayList();
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas = new ArrayList();


                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                    charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
                    HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap();
                    uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                    currentCharaData.put("NAME", "\t\t\t<<" + SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString) + ">>");
                    currentCharaData.put("UUID", "\t\t\tUUID: 0x" + uuid.substring(4, 8) + ", Properties: " + translateProperties(gattCharacteristic.getProperties()));
                    gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);

                    Log.i(TAG,"CUrrent CHARACTERISTIC DATA"+currentCharaData);
                    Log.i(TAG,"UUID : "+uuid.substring(4, 8));
                    Log.i(TAG,"Proprties : "+gattCharacteristic.getProperties());
                    Log.i(TAG,"Translate Proprties : "+translateProperties(gattCharacteristic.getProperties()));
                    Log.i(TAG,"char list"+gattCharacteristicData.toString());

                }
                gattService4=gattService;
                this.mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
            }

            if (mGattCharacteristics.get(3)!=null) {
                lastCharacteristic = new ArrayList<>(mGattCharacteristics.get(3));
                enableNotifyOfCharcteristicForDimmer(lastCharacteristic);

            }


        }
    }

    private String translateProperties(int properties) {
        String s = "";
        if ((properties & 1) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/Broadcast").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 2) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/Read").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 4) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/WriteWithoutResponse").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 8) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/Write").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 16) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/Notify").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 32) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/Indicate").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 64) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/SignedWrite").toString();
        }
        if ((properties & 128) > 0) {
            s = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s)).append("/ExtendedProperties").toString();
        }
        if (s.length() > 1) {
            return s.substring(1);
        }
        return s;
    }


    //    Enable Characteristic for dimmer
    public void enableNotifyOfCharcteristicForDimmer(ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> lastCharacteristic){

        if(mGattCharacteristics!=null) {

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(0));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(0), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+0+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 0 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(0).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(1));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(1), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+1+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 1 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(1).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(2));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(2), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+2+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 2 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(2).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(3));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(3), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+3+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 3 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(3).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(4));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(4), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+4+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 4 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(4).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(5));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(5), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+5+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 5 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(5).toString());

            checkCharacteristicPresent(lastCharacteristic.get(2));
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(lastCharacteristic.get(2), true);
            notificationActive = true;
            Log.e(TAG,"Characteristic index : "+2+":\nM GATT CHARACTERISTIC AT "+"Service 4 : CHAR"+ 2 +" :" +lastCharacteristic.get(2).toString());

        }
    }

    //  Check the type of characteristic i.e READ/WRITE/NOTIFY
    public void checkCharacteristicPresent(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {


        int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
        Log.e(TAG, "checkCharacteristicPresent Prop : " + charaProp);
        mBluetoothLeService.setCurrentCharacteristic(characteristic);

        if ((charaProp & 2) > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CharProp & 2 : " + charaProp);
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        } 
        if ((charaProp & 16) > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CharProp & 16 : " + charaProp);
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;

        } else {
            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
            }
        }

        if ((charaProp & 8) > 0 || (charaProp & 4) > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CharProp & 4 : " + charaProp);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Else : " + charaProp);

        }
    }


}
```

Write this code in manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".service.BackgroundService" />
```